# How to recreate a file using tcpdump and c++?

Tags: python, c++, network-programming, tcpdump

I have the pcap file for duration when the text file was downloading. How can I recreate the original file from this pcap file using python or c++. I don't know much about network programming and am trying to do this to enhance my understanding. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what the pcap file looks like. Assuming that the text file is in the `data` field inside of the tcp layer, you can use tshark like so:

```sh
$ myfile="traffic.pcap"
$ tshark -r $myfile -T fields -e data > myfile.txt
```

If data is not the right field, use [wireshark](https://wireshark.org) to look at the packets to see which is. If the data is actually encrypted (which is pretty common with HTTPS, SSH, etc.), then this is a different question.

With this strategy, you may also get extraneous data from other traffic (you may need to use a [display filter](https://tshark.dev/analyze/packet_hunting/packet_hunting/) on the pcap file for the traffic you're interested in so you just have the text file encapsulated with network headers for easier export).